# GA4 ecommerce items Array do not show up in debug mode

Tags: e-commerce, google-tag-manager

[image]GA4 ecommerce items Array do not show up in debug mode
i am using the GTM,  i am sure i passed the Array for items (using Datalayer or CJS), but GA4 does not recognized it , what i see is missing the items tab in debug mode, i don't know how that could be show up , am i doing something wrong? anyone has the same experience?

[image]

Comment: You might need to show more detail about how you set it. How you set it in GTM? How you prepare the items code?

Comment: i set the parameter from using Datalayer pused data , say: parameter name:items, value : DLV- items (set this datalayer variable using ecommerce.items to get it from datalayer push) , all others variable works well , except for items ,which is an array of products, not working well , the debug mode did not show up items as some other tutorial videos interface  having items, i debug from gtm preview mode ,it also show this datalayer variable is an array , but GA4 seems did not receiving it

Comment: The most possible reason is there something not right in your item or the object structure. Can we see how you populate the items?

Comment: hi, Darrell, i updated some Pics for your reference., see if you can help ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the event name is incorrect here -> `View_Items`.

Make sure that the event name exactly matches `view_item`
(stylized as snake_case).

> As GA4 only allows ecommerce data collection with a set of pre-defined
> event names.

Answer (score 0):

Update :
[image]

I saw this checkbox is being checked

As you already set the `value` `currency` `items` in the event parameter. You can uncheck this setting.

---

I think you can follow Google's document about it

[view_item_details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtag#view_item_details)

```
items: [
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      currency: "USD",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: "green",
      location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
      price: 9.99,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ]
```

Make items array only contain 1 item

Comment: both have tried already , it did not work , for me , if it accept array , it should not just for a item only , that make no sense at all.

Comment: tried , uncheck it . but still did not work out

Answer (score 0):

Google has a list of [recommended events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtm) suggesting that the `items` are automatically collected. If your **custom event name** doesn't match the listed event, GA4 won't take the items data.

**Note that even though you can use the GTM preview mode to check whether the data is correctly constructed, the shown data won't necessarily send to GA4.**

The reason is that GTM only forwards the requested data instead of sending it to GA4 directly. To see this behavior, you may have a look at the dev tool such as Chrome dev tool. You can examine the forwarded request's payload in the network tab (search `/collect.*/`). If it's the recommended event, in payload, there's `pr1`, `pr2`, etc., representing your items' array data; otherwise, you'll see nothing, and thus the data won't show up in the GA4 debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same GTM data layer which initially track for GA Universal events ? If yes, then this may be the cause why the items array did not show on debug view since I found this issue also.

The solution is to create the new GTM Container, and name the data layer differently like 'datalayer2' to differentiate those data layers and set up your config again with 'datalayer2'

for instance, datalayer2.push(
{
event : view_promotion
....}